# Android App : Java crash when clicking on button that should display a random image

Tags: java, android, crash

I have created a button that displays a random image every time you click on it. However:
- it is very slow to display the images 
- sometimes, i have to click 2 times on the button to make it display a new random image

Why ?

Then, I have added more images to my drawable and now the app crashes after displaying 2 images...

Why ?

Here are the java codes - hope all is clear and you can give me a hand

public class nextActivity extends Activity {

```
int[] cards = {R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4,
        R.drawable.image5,
        ...
        R.drawable.image32,
        R.drawable.image33};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

    //   initializing the image view
    ImageView m_imgRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);

    //   choosing a random number from 0 to 33
    int n = new Random().nextInt(33);

    //   choosing the random image from cards array using the random number
    m_imgRandom.setImageResource(cards[n]);




    Button myButtonRoll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRoll);
    myButtonRoll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("openclass", "yay it works!");

            ImageView myRollAgain = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);

            //   choosing a random number from 0 to 33
            int n = new Random().nextInt(33);

            //   choosing the random image from cards array using the random number
            myRollAgain.setImageResource(cards[n]);
        }

    });

}
```

}`

Comment: Post a stacktrace, and possibly your layout xml. This *may* be an issue in AndroidStudio that you can resolve through File>Invalidate caches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ImageView m_imgRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);
ImageView myRollAgain = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);
```

You inject the same view for two times, you already injected it into m_imgRandom, inside your onCLick don't inject it again, just use the same like:

```
 m_imgRandom.setImageResource(cards[n]);
```

Of course if it is another imageView give it an other id.

Comment: Thanks ! it must have been part of the problem. Now, it displays more images of the array, however it still crash sometimes. Can it be due to the size of certain images ?